How do I install torch==1.9.1 in VS Code?
I'm trying to install the libraries from the requirements.txt that looks like this:
torch==1.9.1
torchvision==0.10.1
scikit-learn==0.24.1
numpy==1.20.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
tqdm==4.59.0

This is the error that I get:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.9.1 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.9.1

I've tried installing torch with python 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 and 3.12 and the issue still persists.

I think it's something to do with your pip/anaconda/other package manager version rather than the Python version - that's how you're doing the environment? I think there's some way to install it manually through package files. Search it up for your package manager.

In any case the VScode is only an editor. It has nothing to do about your issue. As for the error you re facing, check out the official site for previous versions of Pytorch.,

If you take a look here at the release info for version 1.9.1 of torch, there is a table for build status. The table does not include Python version 3.9 and above. This version of torch is old and does not support more recent versions of Python.
Additionally, if you look at your error, it shows the available versions of torch currently available for your version of Python that your package manager could find (which does not include 1.9.1 because it is not supported). Consider installing one of those versions or downgrading your Python version.
